# Why is my Codeigniter extended library function not being called?

Tags: ajax, session, codeigniter-2

I have extended the CI_Session class in order to deal with a set_flashdata() issue with Ajax calls as per this forum post (http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/138823/), but for some reason my sess_update() function is never called. I put in a log_message() call in my extension constructor and it is indeed being called.

Why isn't my sess_update() function being called though when I do $this->session->sess_update()?

The session library has been added to the autoload.php config file and I have my extension library in /application/libraries.

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session 
{

  public function MY_Session()
  {
    log_message('debug', 'MY_Session construct');
    parent::__construct();
  }

/**
* Update an existing session
*
* @access    public
* @return    void
*/
    function sess_update()
    {
       // skip the session update if this is an AJAX call!
       if ( !IS_AJAX )
       {
           log_message('debug', 'NOT an AJAX request');
           parent::sess_update();
       } else {
           log_message('debug', 'AJAX request');
       }
    } 

}
```

I also added this to my constants.php file

```
// Define Ajax Request
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is version 3.
If so,
Put MY_Session.php in

```
libraries/Session/MY_Session.php
```

User_Guide is helpful for most questions.

Answer (score 0):

add your class to `application/core` and see if it works

Comment: Tried that with no luck. It's definitely loading the extended class that's in the /application/libraries folder as per the log_message() in the constructor...just not calling the sess_update() function :s

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should locate your classes with `'MY_'` to `application/core` for handle if you want to extend any **model/controller/loader base classes** etc..

Secondly, this can give an idea:

my_session.php

```
include_once(BASEPATH.'libraries/Session.php');

class MY_Session extends CI_Session{
      public function __construct(){
          parent::__construct(); 
          ....
      }
    ....
}
```

In your controller:

```
$this->load->library('MY_Session');
$this->my_session->set_userdata() // or sth
```